# d3.js force layout doesn't run

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm just starting with d3.js and can't get a simple demo to work correctly.
It's tough to debug: If there’s a bug, it often crashes in d3′s minified code with no stack trace. In this case, it doesn’t print any errors to the error console at all.

When I run this code, all my nodes are stuck in position (0,0) instead of being laid out by force(). What's wrong?

```
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var svg = d3.select('#graph').append('svg').attr('width', 900).attr('height', 900)

    var myNodes = [{name:'a'}, {name:'b'}, {name:'c'}]
    var myLinks = [{source:myNodes[0], target:myNodes[1]}, {source:myNodes[1], target:myNodes[2]}, {source:myNodes[2], target:myNodes[0]}]

    svg.append("text").text("myNodes[0].name=" + myNodes[0].name).attr('y', 50)

    var force = d3.layout.force().charge(-120).linkDistance(30).size([900, 900])

    var link = svg.selectAll("line")
                  .data(myLinks)
                  .enter().append("svg:line");

    var node = svg.selectAll("circle")
                  .data(myNodes)
                  .enter().append("svg:circle")
                  .attr("r", 6)
                  .call(force.drag)

    force.nodes(myNodes).links(myLinks).start()
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="graph"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Force just handles [setting x/y attributes on the nodes and links](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-start):

> ... The initial x and y coordinates, if not already set externally to a valid number, are computed by examining neighboring node..

It does not actually handle updating of the corresponding svg shapes. This you would typically do in the [tick event](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-on):

> Listen to tick events to update the displayed positions of nodes

```
force.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});
```

The only other piece missing from your example is setting the style of the lines. By default they have no stroke color so appear invisible. You can either set the color directly on the line, like this:

```
var link = svg.selectAll("line")
              .data(myLinks)
              .enter().append("svg:line")
              .attr('stroke', 'red')
              .attr('stroke-width', 2)
```

Or make a CSS class for them:

```
<style>
.link {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
</style>
```

And tag them with it when you create them:

```
var link = svg.selectAll("line")
              .data(myLinks)
              .enter().append("svg:line")
              .attr('class', 'link')
```